# iPad - xib ignoring orientation on view loads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview, interface-builder

iPad question:

We have views that we're initializing from .xibs, with each .xib containing both landscape and portrait layouts.

The first view we load respects the orientation of the device, but any subsequent views seem to have confusion over which orientation they should be using.  Or, rather, they seem to ignore orientation altogether and go with whichever orientation the .xib file was saved with.  (i.e. We saved a .xib file in landscape, and even though the device was held in portrait position, it loaded the view from the .xib with a landscape layout.)

This is how we're calling in these views:

```
Settings *settingsTEMP = [[Settings alloc] init];
self.settings = settingsTEMP;
[self.view insertSubview:settings.view atIndex:0];
[settingsTEMP release];
```

The first of the calls (the one that respects the device's orientation) is in the viewDidLoad. The second, which uses a different view (the one that doesn't respect the device's orientation) is in a method that's called after a button is pressed, but uses the same syntax.

If we put both into viewDidLoad, they both respect the orientation.

We've tried searching for anyone having similar issues but have been thus far unsuccessful.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following

```
        
UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
            (toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) 
    {
        NSLog(@"vSettings UIDeviceOrientationLandscape");
        CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
        vSettings.bounds = contentRect;
        CGRect myFrame = vSettings.frame;
        myFrame.origin.x = 0.0;
        myFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
        vSettings.frame = myFrame;
        UIImage *image;
            image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Default-Landscape.png"];
        [backGroundSettings setImage:image];
        }
```

I hate having to do this as it seems a right fudge but it works for me. Called just after I create the view.